# How should i handle public properties?

Tags: vb.net, linq, class, properties

Within my application i have a PUBLIC customer class...

```
Public Class Customer
    Public Name As String
    Public Surname As String
End Class
```

Then i decided to use LINQ to SQL within my application.
After adding the `MyDatabase.dbml` class, errors showed up since LINQ creates public properties too

```
<Column(Storage:="_Name", DbType:="NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull:=false)>  _
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Name
        End Get
```

Here are some errors..

`'Name' is already declared as 'Public Name As String' in this class.`

`'SurName' is already declared as 'Public SurName As String' in this class.`

Ok. Thats logical.

But what is the best-practice i should use in the future? 
I would not like to use the Name and Pluralization options mentioned in [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx) or rename the properties of my Customer class.

Is there any trick that i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code didn't have properties. It had public fields. They a bad idea, basically.

You should just remove the original fields, and use the ones that LINQ to SQL has generated for you. Why would you want *two* fields (_Name and Name) storing the customer's name, for example?

Comment: Hello Jon! Actually the original code has properties. What i wrote above is an example. Unfortunately i cannot remove the original ones. (You see it would be easier to write the application from scratch :)

Comment: @strakastroukas: Examples are generally more useful if they actually represent the real situation. Now *why* can't you remove the original properties? Do you actually need the existing classes to become LINQ to SQL entities, or could you have separate classes?

Comment: Basically i would not like to remove them because i am making a lot of checks within the properties. I do not want the existing classes to become LINQ to SQL entities. I just want to learn LINQ and create XML files from my database.

Comment: @strakastroukas: If you don't want the existing classes to become LINQ to SQL entities, then create the LINQ to SQL classes with different names, or in a different namespace etc.

Comment: Aha! I 'll take the different namespace option! Thank you.